# Postgres has a lot of activity going on despite me not doing anything

Tags: django, postgresql

[image]

I am running a local development server. I am working on the project until it is ready for deployment. I checked the postgres admin page and I noticed that I have a lot of transactions running in the background.

I am not using the site/making queries, and am wondering what is causing this. (I am also the only user)

Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to find out what is going on yourself.

First, you can try `SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity` ([doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-ACTIVITY-VIEW)). It shows the last statement executed by each user.
With some luck, you'll find out what is going on.

If that is not enough, use [pg_stat_statements](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgstatstatements.html).
It is a little bit more complicated to install (load in postgresql.conf then `CREATE EXTENSION pg_stat_statements`) but you will not miss any of the queries.

Comment: If you see anything worth mentioning but still can't figure out, please edit your question with new elements. I'll come check that out.